# Как избежать дублирования содержания поля?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

В таблице есть `id, id_login, domain, confirm_domain`. Необходимо сделать, чтобы домен не повторялся. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать в таблице естественный первичный ключ.

Comment: @msi первичный ключ у айди записи...а уникальный другие поля

Comment: Если у вас есть уникальные ключи, то откуда тогда берутся дубликаты?

Comment: @msi  в таблице есть id id_login domain confirm_domain
необходимо сделать чтобы домен не повторялся. что посоветуете?

Comment: @Анатолийй, а что тут можно посоветовать? Ищите запись в таблице с тем доменом, который добавляете и если такой записи еще нет, то добавляете новую.

Comment: Поставить ограничение UNIQUE.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, у нас есть переменная $text, в ней хранится то, что нужно добавить, тогда получаем следующее:

```
if ($result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text`=:text"))
{

    $result->bindParam(":text",$text,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
    $assoc = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
if($assoc['text'] == $text){
die("Дубль!");
}else{
// записываем
}
```

Или правильнее будет:

```
if (isset($assoc['text'])){
die("Дубль!");
}else{
// записываем
}
```

Comment: @Виталий RS только что такое prepare и PRO::PARAM_STR PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: @Анатолийй
prepare означает подготовленный запрос
PARAM_STR - говорит PDO, что данные - строка.
FETCH_ASSOC - преобразование ответа от базы в ассоциативный массив.

Comment: Почитайте:

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

В общем, как-то так:

```
    $domain = 'Добавляемый домен';
    $query = 'SELECT id FROM table WHERE domain = ' . $domain;
    if ($result = mysqli_query($database, $query)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            /* Добавляем новую запись */
        } else {
            /* Ошибка! Такая запись уже есть */
        }
    }
```